# Using jQuery to fade one class to another

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein

i am trying to fade a class as "hover" in over a link with a class.
so the hover class has to fade in to represent a hover effect.

my css class for the a tag has a gradient applied to it in one color, and the other class representing the "hover" effect has a different color gradient applied to it.

I tried this, but it is not the desired effect, the hover class should just fade in and out, without the normal class disappearing first.

```
$("a").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("btn").addClass("btn2").fadeIn('fast');
                });
            },
            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("btn2").addClass("btn").fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        );
```

Comment: can you provide the html and css i tried to work with normal text-color effect it work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.animate('opacity','0.5');`
On hover of `<a>` it will also show fading effect.

Answer (score -1):

try using toggleclass function

```
$("a").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).fadeInOut(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn btn2');
                });
            },
            }
        );
```

Comment: firstly there is an error in your code. but even after fixing it it does not work. thanks for trying

Comment: Sorry, I just copy pasted that code. can you try   $(function () {
            $("a").mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('aa');
                $(this).addClass('bb');
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
            });
            $("a").mouseout(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('bb');
                $(this).addClass('aa');
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
            });
        });

Comment: this works for changing the class, but it does not fadeIn or OUt